# Excel filter multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, autofilter, advanced-filter

I have a datasheet with 1300 rows. Each row is numbered by a specific number linked to our database. I need to filter everything by two arguments 5 times.

- First one: filter everything ending on 0 and 1
- Second filter: filer everything ending on 2 and 3
- etc
- etc.
- fifth filter: filter everything ending on 8 and 9

I need to use these filters seperately because different people will use it.

example: person 1 will need to see data with the ending numbers 2 and 3
person 2 will need to see data with the ending numbers 6 and 7

I can filter the data with one argument like `*5` or `*8` but when I try to use 2 arguments divided by `""`, `OR`, `AND` it won't work.

Advanced filtering also doesn't want to use my two arguments. When I put these 2 criteria in different cells and select them as criteria. The result will be blank. And when I only select one criteria like `*5`, the filter will make no sense because it will also show cells ending with other numbers.

I expect the result to be a formula I can use in my advanced filter or a VBA code as I will be implementing it in a small script to make it as easy as possible to use for my colleagues. And an explanaition would be much appreciated so others and me can implement it in a different way.

Comment: Some questions: ① Can you please provide some example data (see [mcve]). ② Are these values (you want to filter) saved as numbers or text in the cells?

Comment: (1)
123093
123078
123124
123110
123131
123100
123134
123180
123183
123217
123218
123228
123233
123239
(2) As Numbers

Comment: If they are numbers you cannot use textfilers like `*` you need to use number filters. Therefore see my workaround answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Indirect (workaround) solution

Since you have real numbers in the column you want to filter at, you cannot use text filters with asterisks `*` and must use number filters. Therfore you would need to use a helper column for filtering, that shows only the last digit of your numbers.

Add the following formula to your helper column:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A:A,1))
```

So it looks like in the picture below.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Added helper column showing the ending digit only.</sup>*

Now you can filter for the exact ending numbers `1` or `2` (using `xlOr`),

```
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=2"
```

or even on ending ranges like `1-5` by using the numeric in between filter `>=1` and `<=5` with `xlAnd`.

```
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=1", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=5"
```

[image]
*<sup>Image 2: Data filtered by ending digits, showing only ending digits from 1 to 5.</sup>*

Comment: With a bit of tweaking i got it to work. In the formula i had to change the comma into a semicolon    . and i neede to add the worksheets and range into the code. Thanks!

Comment: @KeesKameel The formulas here are always meant for an US English Excel. Localized Excel versions of other countries might always need a localization of the formulas (since they somtimes use different separators `,` or `;` and also the function names might be translated into the country's language).